# Find value of attribute when value of sibling is known only

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Thanks to some great answers I now understand how to use LINQ to XML to find elements in an XML file.

I am struggling with the following: To find the value of an attribute from which I know its siblings value only:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Douglas Adams</author>
        <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
        <price>42</price>
        <locationId>1</locationId>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Douglas Adams</author>
        <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
        <price>42</price>
        <locationId>2</locationId>
        <quantity>7</quantity>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Douglas Adams</author>
        <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
        <price>42</price>
        <locationId>3</locationId>
        <quantity>20</quantity>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Douglas Adams</author>
        <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
        <price>42</price>
        <locationId>4</locationId>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </book>
</books>
```

How would I find the quantity of the book if I know the location ID only? Let's say I would like the `quantity` for `locationId = 3`.

My approach would be to create a loop and stop as soon as I find the desired location ID. Does this sound like the best approach? Is there an easier way to accomplish this using LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Descendants` method to get all the books, and then you can filter using `Where` extension method and project with `Select` ext. method the `quantity`:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var result=xdoc.Descendants("book")
               .Where(e=>(int)e.Element("locationId")==3)
               .Select(e=>(int)e.Element("quantity"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Code has a Typo, `doc` and `xdoc` variables are not same

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an issue with the closing tag of `locationId`

Linq-To-Xml has a `NodesAfterSelf` method, so if the oreder of tags is always the same you can use:

```
var quantityElement = xdoc.Descendants("locationId")
             .First(l=>l.Value=="3")
             .NodesAfterSelf()
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit -

Actually the above can throw an exception if there's no location found. The following will not.

```
var quantityElement = xdoc
             .Descendants("locationId")
             .Where(l=>l.Value=="3")
             .SelectMany(l=>l.NodesAfterSelf())
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ofir. That was just a typo regarding the closing tag. Will fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

For VB'ers that might need this functionality.  The following solution does not make assumptions about tag order.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'for testing
    xe = <books>
             <book>
                 <author>Douglas Adams</author>
                 <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
                 <price>42</price>
                 <locationId>1</locationId>
                 <quantity>0</quantity>
             </book>
             <book>
                 <author>Douglas Adams</author>
                 <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
                 <price>42</price>
                 <locationId>2</locationId>
                 <quantity>7</quantity>
             </book>
             <book>
                 <author>Douglas Adams</author>
                 <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
                 <price>42</price>
                 <locationId>3</locationId>
                 <quantity>20</quantity>
             </book>
             <book>
                 <author>Douglas Adams</author>
                 <title>The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</title>
                 <price>42</price>
                 <locationId>4</locationId>
                 <quantity>5</quantity>
             </book>
         </books>

    'the answer - by selecting the <book> all nodes are available.
    Dim aBook As XElement = xe...<book>.SingleOrDefault(Function(el) el.<locationId>.Value = "3")

    'verification
    If aBook IsNot Nothing Then
        Debug.WriteLine(aBook.<quantity>.Value)
        Debug.WriteLine(aBook.<author>.Value)
        Debug.WriteLine(aBook.<title>.Value)
    End If
```